# Show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n}(-1)^n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

How would you show that  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n}(-1)^n$ converges?

---

**My approach**

At first glance I would go for the alternate series criterion and show that $\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n}$ is a monotone sequence with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n}=0$. So after a few algebraic manipulations I get:

$$
\frac{\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n}}{\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{n+1}}=
\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n(n+1)}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)n}=
\left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)^{n}\cdot \frac{n+1}{\frac{n^2+2n}{n+1}}=
\cdots=\frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^2+2n}\left(\frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^2+2n}\right)^n\geq1.
$$
So the expression is monotonically decreasing. Further, we know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e^1$. Hence, $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is bounded, say $S\geq\Big| \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\Big|$. This allows us to conclude:
$$
\Big| \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n}-0\Big|\leq \frac{S}{n}<\epsilon,\text{ where n is sufficiently large enough}.
$$
Hence, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n}=0$ and by the alternate series crterion the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n}(-1)^n$ converges.

Is this correct? Is there a faster way?

Comment: This might help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359591/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-left-1-frac1n-right-n2-cdot

Comment: The numerator is less than 3, now use comparison and alt series criteria

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
2\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le3
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^n}n=\log2
$$
Calling $S$ the desired limit (that is, your sum), you can immediately get that
$$
2\log 2\le S\le3\log 2\;.
$$

Comment: just to make sure that I understand your argument correctly, you say that the sum converges because it is the product of a bounded sequence and another series which is convergent, right?

Comment: More properly: the general term is the product of the general term of a well known convergent series (namely $\frac{(-1)^n}n$) with a sequence which is bounded with constant sign.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by _bounded with constant sign_? Do you have Abel's test in mind where the sequence must be monotone?

Comment: Bounded AND with constant sing. $(-1)^n$ is bounded but not with constant sign, for example

Comment: ok so you have a bounded sequence $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ which has a constant sign on the one hand and on the other hand you have the convergent series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Then, how do you conclude the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$? What is your exact argument that the series converges?

Comment: ok: keep it simple. call $a_n:=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\frac1n$. Then it's clear that $a_n\ge0$ and $a_n\to0$. Then by Leibnitz $\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^na_n$ converges.

Comment: ah okay then it's exactly the same way I did it in my proof.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n= e^{n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=e^{1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}=e-\frac e{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

therefore

$$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n}=\frac e n-\frac e{2n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: can you elaborate on the third equal sign in the first line?

Comment: @Philipp We have that $e^{1+x}=ee^x=e(1+x+O(x^2)$.

Comment: is it wrong to argue with a bound bound/big-O-notation which is less strict, like: $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n}=e^{n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\cdot \frac{1}{n}=e^{\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}\pm\cdots\right)}\cdot \frac{1}{n}= \left(e^1+ O(\frac{1}{n})\right)\cdot \frac{1}{n}=O(\frac{1}{n})$, hence we get for sufficient large $n>n_0$: $$\sum\limits_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \frac{1}{n}(-1)^n=\sum\limits_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty}O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)(-1)^n,$$ which converges due to alternate series test.